# How to check for each char of a string in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, char

I've got a homework for a function that checks if a username is valid or not. Allowed chars are underscore, letters, and digits. I'm not allowed to use indexing (!!) and Length

My code so far:

```
isValid' :: Char -> Bool
isValid' x
     | x == '_'    = True
     | x `elem` ['0'..'9'] = True
     | x `elem` ['a'..'z'] = True
     | x `elem` ['A'..'Z'] = True
     | otherwise           = False

isValidUsername :: [Char] -> Bool
isValidUsername x
     | map isValid' x = True
     | otherwise     = False
```

I want to run my isValid function on all chars of the string i put in isValidUsername. For example:

`isValidUsername "MyUsername_123"` should return True

`isValidUsername "not@v@lidusern@me* *2"` should return False

I just can't figure out how to run through all the chars of my string.

Comment: "*run my isValid function on **all** chars of the string*" --> [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all)

Comment: As a style suggestion, you don't have to write `f .. | condition = True ; | otherwise = False`. Your `condition` already evaluated to the wanted boolean, so you can simply write `f .. = condition`, without guards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you want *all* the elements to satisfy the `isValid'` function, you can use the [**`all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) function, so you can rewrite your function to:

```
isValidUsername :: [Char] -> Bool
isValidUsername x = all isValid' x
```

or even shorter:

```
isValidUsername :: [Char] -> Bool
isValidUsername = all isValid'
```

Note that here it means that the *empty string* `""` is a valid username as well, since for an empty string, all characters (there are no characters) are in the alphanumerical range.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, i figured it out:

```
isValidUsername :: [Char] -> Bool
isValidUsername x
     | False `elem` (map isValid x) = False
     | otherwise                    = True
```

Comment: Whenever one of your functions returns `True` or `False` explicitly, it can (probably) be simplified.